# How to make images I download within my app show in default gallery?

Tags: android

I made an application that has as one of it's features file sharing, and the files sent may be anything. However, Images and Videos sent are not showing up on the default Gallery app using the com.androidquery.AQuery download. Is there a step I'm missing that would mark the file as media or something like that? Because I thought you only needed to mark file as NOT media on Android when you really don't want them to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research based on Sone's answer, I got this code I needed to insert after the download:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadFilePath)); //Insert your file path here

Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
mediaScanIntent.setData(uri);
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

As he said, I needed to register my file in android MediaStore, and this code does that no matter what type of media is downloaded by forcing the scanner to go over the recently downloaded file. Hope it helps anyone else needing this.

Answer (score 2):

After file downloading you need to execute

```
private void addImageGallery(File file) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

To register your file in android MediaStore where gallery takes data about stored media files

Comment: Hey, this limited the immediate adding to a type, but based on this answer I found what I was needing, thanks! Sorry I can't vote up your answer, I'm new at stack overflow.